# Give a state diagram for an NFA whose language L = ...

Tags: computer-science, automata

L = {w ∈ {0,1,2} *: w is a ternary representation of an integer that is a multiple of 3 but not a multiple of 9}

I've written a [DFA accepting multiples of 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpXy1.jpg), but I'm not sure how I should proceed. Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Comment: So the automaton should accept all words which end on 0 but not on 00.

Comment: Your ternary representations allow leading zeroes. Maybe check tio find out whether this is really allowed. In your automaton you can merge $q_1$ and $q_2$. Further, it accepts the empty word. Again it is not clear whether this is a valid ternary number.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for a NFA, and taking into account the comments by Wuestenfux and Peter Leupold, three states should suffice:

[image]

Note that there are three initial states in this automaton.